# get driving distance from latitude and longitude via google api

Tags: php, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

I have read documentation of google api but I am not able to get driving distance from two points of latitude/longitude

my question is I have two points with latitude/longitude
for example

```
latitude1 = -35.397
longitude1 = 150.644

latitude2 = -35.00
longitude2 = 150.644
```

I want driving distance from google api

Comment: maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=-35.397,150.644&destination=35.00-150.644&sensor=false
I have fire this query to url and gives output as
{
   "routes" : [],
   "status" : "ZERO_RESULTS"
}

Comment: There must be some issue with the coordinates you are inputting. I do not know what it is, but I get the same response when I try your query. However, I went on Google maps and got some arbitrary latitude and longitude coordinates, plugged them into the query string, and it worked fine. This is the query I used: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=39.565471,-107.519073&destination=39.477546,-108.007965&sensor=false

Comment: Yes you are right I was also thinking about this because I have inputed random attribute and I have seen that both are on ocean lol
thanks for help